# Debian 8 Jessie KEYEXPIRED 1587841717

Tags: debian, apt, gpg

I've got the problem, that the "apt-get update" produced a KEYEXPIRED 1587841717 error:

```
# apt-get update
...
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org jessie Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717
```

Here my sources.list:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie contrib
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie contrib
```

Here the expired keys found by apt-key (it seems that the key 46925553 expired on 2020-04-25):

```
apt-key list | grep expired -A1
pub   4096R/46925553 2012-04-27 [expired: 2020-04-25]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
--
pub   4096R/65FFB764 2012-05-08 [expired: 2019-05-07]
uid                  Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>
--
pub   4096R/B98321F9 2010-08-07 [expired: 2017-08-05]
uid                  Squeeze Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>
--
pub   4096R/473041FA 2010-08-27 [expired: 2018-03-05]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
--
pub   4096R/65FFB764 2012-05-08 [expired: 2019-05-07]
uid                  Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>
--
pub   4096R/46925553 2012-04-27 [expired: 2020-04-25]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
```

Now i tried to renew the keys:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 46925553
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 65FFB764
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys B98321F9
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 473041FA
```

But the keys are not changed:

```
# apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 46925553
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.Ue8AFETZOi --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/turnkey.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntuzilla.firefox.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 46925553
gpg: requesting key 46925553 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 46925553: "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

A new "apt-get update" get the same error like above.

Can anybody help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 14):

At the time of this writing (August 2023), there are (at least!) two things worth noting about this question:

1. Jessie is only available on the Debian Archive site `archive.debian.org`.
2. The signing keys for Jessie have both expired and have not been replaced. As such, the (currently) highest-ranked answer of downloading 'debian-archive-keyring' will not help. These expired keys are what is causeing the `KEYEXPIRED 1587841717` error listed in the OP's question.

While the safest answer is certainly to upgrade to something supported in the current decade, you probably found this question because you are using hardware that has not been supported past Jessie *(looking at you ReadyNAS)*.

In the situation where you cannot upgrade the distro, the next safest solution I can see is to set the specific entries in `sources.list` to be trusted by adding `[trusted=yes]` after the archive type (i.e. `deb`).  So your `sources.list` file may look something like this:

```
# Keys Expired But I ~~Want~~ Need To Hold On To The Past
deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
```

`apt-get` will still throw the warning about the expired signing key, but it will no longer error from it.

If you've come this far, you know that running such equipment outside of the Smithsonian is a terrible idea, and that you are just asking to be compromised.  But here we are.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that the keys are no more checked at all.  As the download is `http`, it is **extremely easy to alter the download on the fly** and put a trojan (horse) into the `.deb`.  So you are better advised to download `archive.debian.org` to a local repo on a trusted machine, **verify it** (I have not the slightest idea how!) and then use that.

Comment: @Tino technically you can use https but it I am not sure whether trusted=yes also disable SSL certificate checks.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to download the latest `debian-archive-keyring` package for Debian jessie by hand and install it using `dpkg -i`.  You can find a link to it on [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/debian-archive-keyring).  You could also use the stretch package.

Note that jessie has reached end of life and is not being security supported further.  Because unpatched systems are easy to compromise and compromised systems are often used to attack other systems, you should consider upgrading promptly to a supported version so as not to be a hazard to the Internet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but it dont work. I installed the package `dpkg -i debian-archive-keyring_2017.5~deb8u1_all.deb` but the same error occur. `W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org jessie Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717`. Yes, you are right! I should upgrade to a newer version, but why expired the keyring in april of 2020 when the version reached end of live in june of 2020?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like Debian Jessie has a new key now. I was able to import it with:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com 7638D0442B90D010
```

Answer (score 5):

Debian ELTS ([Extended Long Time Support](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Extended)) releases from freexian helped me, it gives support for jessie until 2025.

From
https://www.freexian.com/lts/extended/docs/how-to-use-extended-lts/ :

---

manually install the freexian-archive-keyring package with

```
wget https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/pool/main/f/freexian-archive-keyring/freexian-archive-keyring_2022.06.08_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i freexian-archive-keyring_2022.06.08_all.deb
```

If you want all packages from Debian 8
Here’s what you should put in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/extended-lts.list`:

```
deb http://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts jessie main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Lovely! this is so much more helpful!

Comment: not for powerpc

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me (upgrading an old system to Debian 8 on its way to Debian 9):

```
sed -i 's;http://archive.debian.org/debian;http://deb.debian.org/debian;' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update
```

Comment: This won't work for an already unsupported architecture such as powerpc.

Comment: doesn't work. get command not found for `apt`, have to use `apt-get`, and get 404s when doing update.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution that worked for me is this:

```
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debian-archive-keyring/debian-archive-keyring_2023.4_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i debian-archive-keyring_2023.4_all.deb

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```