# Debian 8.3 Jessie KEYEXPIRED 11645052400

Tags: debian, upgrade

***EDITION (05/17/2023):** I saw the [Debian 8 Jessie KEYEXPIRED 1587841717](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/598344) question before, and I'd done the renewing of expired keys. There were other expired keys that were renewed, but the 1645052400 key (it appears three times) persists in the "expired" status. Because I think it's an exception, I created this question.*

Trying to upgrade **Debian 8.3 Jessie to Debian 10.13 Buster**, I continue getting "KEYEXPIRED" error message after run `apt-get update`, even renewing expired keys:

```
    # apt-key list | grep -A 1 expired
    pub   1024D/5072E1F5 2003-02-03 [expired: 2022-02-16]
    uid                  MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
    --
    pub   4096R/518E17E1 2013-08-17 [expired: 2021-08-15]
    uid                  Jessie Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>
    --
    pub   4096R/65FFB764 2012-05-08 [expired: 2019-05-07]
    uid                  Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>


# apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 5072E1F5 ; apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 518E17E1 ; apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 65FFB764
    Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.dux8x5wGCC --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apt.postgresql.org.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 5072E1F5
    gpg: requesting key 5072E1F5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
    gpg: key 5072E1F5: "MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>" not changed
    gpg: Número total processado: 1
    gpg:              não modificados: 1
    Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.4zdbdTUejR --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apt.postgresql.org.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 518E17E1
    gpg: requesting key 518E17E1 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
    gpg: key 518E17E1: "Jessie Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>" not changed
    gpg: Número total processado: 1
    gpg:              não modificados: 1
    Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.SxFd1nEp2W --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apt.postgresql.org.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 65FFB764
    gpg: requesting key 65FFB764 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
    gpg: key 65FFB764: "Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>" not changed
    gpg: Número total processado: 1
    gpg:              não modificados: 1


# apt-get update
...
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
W: Ocorreu um erro durante a verificação da assinatura. O repositório não está actualizado e serão utilizados os ficheiros anteriores de índice. Erro do GPG: http://repo.mysql.com jessie InRelease: As seguintes assinaturas eram inválidas: KEYEXPIRED 1645052400 KEYEXPIRED 1645052400 KEYEXPIRED 1645052400
...
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance,
Alan

Comment: I can't say whether it's a dupe, but are you aware of this similar question? [Debian 8 Jessie KEYEXPIRED 1587841717](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/598344)

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend going from Jessie to Buster without going through Stretch first. Alternatively just reinstall with the current stable release, Bullseye, as Buster is already out of date

Comment: @Kusalananda , I saw it before, and I'd done the renewing of expired keys. There were other expired keys that were renewed, but the 1645052400 key (it appears three times) persists in the "expired" status.

Comment: @roaima , ok, I'm trying to upgrade to 9 Stretch before doing it to 10 Buster. I'll return with feedback. Thanks.

Comment: @roaima, it failed, even updating my sources.list as following:

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

The output of apt update/upgrade included GPG Error ("NO_PUBKEY A07310D369055D5A") and the known "KEYEXPIRED 1645052400". I even imported the public key with command "apt-key adv ...", but the expired key continues.

Comment: @AlanHomobono try disabling the mysql repo while you're upgrading?